# What does the vector $[0,1,1]$ have to do with the plane $x=2$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors, gre-exam, tangent-line

From the Princeton book for the GRE Subject Test in Maths:

---

[image]

---

I want to understand how the Princeton book came up with $[0 \ 1 \ 1]$ before the parameterisation. This is how I answered it:

---

On the plane $x=2$, the slope of the tangent line to $z=\arctan(2y)$ at $(\frac12, \frac\pi4)$ is 1.

The equation of the tangent line (which lies on the plane $x=2$) is $z=my+b$ where $m=1$ at $(y,z) = (\frac12, \frac\pi4)$. Hence, it is $z=1y+\frac\pi4 - \frac12$.

In xyz-space, the equation of the tangent line is

$$x=2$$
$$z=y+\frac\pi4 - \frac12$$

or parametrically

$$x=2$$
$$y=s$$
$$z=s+\frac\pi4 - \frac12$$

where $s=\frac12 + t$

or

$$[x \ y \ z] = \color{red}{[0 \ 1 \ 1]}s + [2 \ 0 \ \frac\pi4 - \frac12]$$

Comment: Hint: see page $112$.

Comment: If the tangent line is in a plane $v$ , then any vector that lies in $v$ can serve as a direction vector for that line. The y-component is $1$ as shown in the calculation

Comment: It has nothing to do with the plane $x=2$; it is just a convenient vector parallel to the tangent line. The vector is used to write out the parametric equation.

Comment: @FeiLi 1 I skipped cylinders. I'll check out 112 later. 2 Thought more about it and got the answer. Edited my post. I still don't see how $[0,1,1]$ is parallel to the tangent line prior to the parameterisation. Cmiiw, but one first comes up with the parameterisation and then deduces $[0,1,1]$?

Comment: @imranfat Thought more about it and got the answer. Edited my post. I still don't see how $[0,1,1]$ is parallel to the tangent line prior to the parameterisation. Cmiiw, but one first comes up with the parameterisation and then deduces $[0,1,1]$?

Comment: @BCLC I have an answer, but need time to write it up

Comment: @imranfat In re to your answer, did you mean y-component and not z-component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parametric equation of the curve is $<2,t,arctan(2t)>$ Its derivative is thus $<0,1,\frac{2}{1+4t^2}>$. At the given point (for t=1/2) the direction is $<0,1,1>$. From here we get $x=2,y=1/2+t,z=\pi/2+t$ which is the parametric equation of the line. I think this way is easier than the approach of the book.